# Yahoo finance java api to read recommendation rating, upgrades and downgrades

Tags: java, rest, yahoo-finance

I am getting stockquote from YahooFinance.get(symbol), but how to read recommendation rating, upgrades and downgrades for particular symbol from Java API or any REST services.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought that the Yahoo! Finance API was shut down...

Comment: Web scraping is the only and unreliable option.

Comment: Thank you for reply...is there any other finance java api to read buy ratings along with symbol data such as history, price, 52 week high, 52 week low etc.